# Passing function to angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have my directive:

```
<editable comp="comp" key="'quantity'" input-type="'number'" ed-on-change="save()"></editable>
```

My directive function:

```
function editable() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            comp: '=comp',
            key: '=key',
            inputType: '=inputType',
            edOnChange: '=edOnChange'
        },
        templateUrl: '/Partials/Editable.html',
```

This is run in a `ng-repeat`, so gets hit about 20 times. I do a `console.log('saved')` in the `save()` function in the controller scope, and it outputs 20 times.

Is there a way to stop this function getting fired when `$compile` or `$apply` is called (as I am guessing this is what is causing it)?

Coincidently I don't see `ng-click` with the same behaviour, so  I might go look into the source code in the mean time.

**SOLVED BUT NOT IDEAL**

So just by removing the `()` on the `save` in the `ed-on-change` so passing in the reference of the save function, then just calling it when I want to.

Comment: Do you want the save() to not be called on $compile?

Comment: What I am asking is, is the calling of the save() function the problem?

Comment: It should only be called if I ask it to be called in the directive link function. It would be a massive performance hit on the server if it were called 20 times, before it was supposed to fired.

Comment: Because the scope is isolated, if I remove that, I won't be able to access it in the `link()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use `$parse`.

```
<editable ed-on-change="save()"></editable>
```

In the directive:

```
.directive('editable', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var changeCallback = $parse(attrs.edOnChange) || null;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I pass functions to directives is like this:

```
<editable ... ed-on-change="save"></editable>
```

Notice I removed the `()`.

Then, in the directive I'll have in the scope declaration the same way you wrote.

And I'll have in the `Editable.html`:

```
<div .. ng-click="edOnChange()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The digest loop will always call the functions that are in attribute names because this is how it sets the value of that attribute.

If you are trying to pass the name of a function into the directive for the directive to call when some event happens then you should make it just the name of that function e.g. ed-on-change="save".

It seems to me like what you are doing here is not quite the "Angular" way, if you add more information, I can provide a better solution.